# Preferences being enabled dependent on other Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am currently working on an droid app and was wondering if there is a way that a preference can be enabled or disabled based on the value of another preference.

For example, if I have checkbox_pref1 if this is enabled then option2/3/4 are enabled, if checkbox_pref1 is disabled option2/3/4 automatically become disabled or is this there an XML attribute that would accomplish this or is it something that I would need to code to achieve this effect.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this with the `dependency` attribute. In your `Preference` XML, you would add the following line to your `checkbox_pref2`, `checkbox_pref3`, and `checkbox_pref2` Preferences:

```
android:dependency="checkbox_pref1"
```

Useful Links:

[Android Quick Preferences Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html)

[Android Preference Documentation (#dependency)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:dependency)

Answer (score 8):

Here is my example of disabling a PreferenceScreen until the main checkboxpreference is checked - Thanks kcoppock!  Sorry, my rep not high enough to up you.

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/Day1_title"
            android:summary="@string/Day1_summary"
            android:key="pref_Day1" />
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:dependency="pref_Day1"
            android:key="day1_screen"
            android:summary="@string/Extra_Options">
            <EditTextPreference
              android:title="@string/Day1_title"
              android:summary="@string/Workout_Date"
              android:key="Day1_date"/>
            <EditTextPreference
              android:title="@string/Comment_title"
              android:key="Day1_comment"/>
        </PreferenceScreen>
```